# How do I attack from the sea?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I tried to wage war with France from Scotland, but for some reason I could not attack from the sea tile, while an allied army was. How do I attack from the sea? In general, why can't I land on blocks that are not mine?

Comment: Your ships can't dock on enemy lands, but you can select the army on the ship, and move them manually. Same when embarking from enemy occupied territory. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160518/embarking-and-disembarking

Comment: Thanks, kinda found that out while playing as the bastard.